# User tracking in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I am littlebit new to the codeignitor framework.But love the simplicity.

I have a application requirement that the system need to log all the user activities.

Ex : if a user logged in :then i need something like `<username> logged in <time>`
If he edit his profile : then i need `<username> <edited> <time>`

or something like this .

So that the administrator can review all the activities ...

is there any libraries available ?or how can i achieve this with most perfect way in terms of performance?

Please suggest me some common methods .. and opinions .

Thank you.

Comment: here is a common method: write a logger

Comment: @tereško thanks ..will log u shortly ..

Answer (score 0):

For maximum flexibility write your own log function. When I need this functionality I include the following function/method in every framework that I use. Wordpress/Codeigniter, etc...

```
function log($msg = '', $level = 'INFO')
{
    $debug_backtrace = debug_backtrace();

    $time = date('c', time());
    $filename = PATH_TO_YOUR_SCRIPT . '/log/error_log.txt'; // file perms: 0646

    $output = "[$level] $time $msg\n";
    $output .= "{$debug_backtrace[0]['file']} : {$debug_backtrace[0]['line']}\n";

    if ( ! @file_put_contents($filename, $output, FILE_APPEND))
    {
        error_log("Failed to access log file [$filename] for writing: $msg");
    }
}
```

[debug-backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) allow get the file and line where log function is called

Comment: there is a native log function available on codeignitor ..i need the use of DB ...and this is not a debug level tracker ..i need the user activity ..

Comment: I know about those CI functions. I said `For maximum flexibility`... I use this logger for any kind of messages (debug/user control, etc.) to be written into an (easy to read) text file. You can code `$output` as you want and use `global $wpdb;` too.

Comment: Ok , agree . What i need is the use of DB ..is there any way ? or libraries available instead of text file ?